# How to Order methods in a class using Junit play framework

Tags: junit, playframework, playframework-1.x, testcase

Please help me with this.
I am using the functional Test in Junit in Play 1.2.4.
Hence using ApplicationTest.java

```
import org.junit.Before;

import org.junit.Test;

import play.test.FunctionalTest;

public class ApplicationTest extends FunctionalTest {

@Before
public void setUp() {
    System.out.println("abc");
}

@Test
public void priority1() {
    System.out.println("P1");    
    assertTrue(true);}
@Test
public void priority3() {
    System.out.println("P3");    
    assertTrue(true);}
@Test
public void priority2() {
    System.out.println("P2");    
    assertTrue(true);}
}
```

I need the test to be run in the order priority1, priority2 and then priority3.
How possibly can I achieve that, without upgrading the Play version or using any other testing tool.
Please  help me with this!

Answer (score 0):

JUnit 4.11 has support for test order.

```
import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;

@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class ApplicationTest extends FunctionalTest {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Oh Thanks, thats a knowledge I acquired just right now. But I actually need an ordering of methods within few classes that too custom ordering. As in in accordance with the flow of a functionality.